# How to set InAppWebView Camera/Micro permissions in Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter

I've created an ios application with Flutter 2.5.0.
One of the application widgets uses InAppWebView with a page that is using camera/micro.

```
return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
    title: const Text('XPTO'),),
    body: SafeArea(
      child: Column(children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              InAppWebView(
                key: webViewKey,
                initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(url: Uri.parse(app.url.toString())),
                initialOptions: options,
                androidOnPermissionRequest: (InAppWebViewController controller, String origin, List<String> resources) async {
                  return PermissionRequestResponse(resources: resources, action: PermissionRequestResponseAction.GRANT);
                },
                onWebViewCreated: (controller) async  {
                  webViewController = controller;
                },
          )])
        )
      ]
  )
));
```

the options object for the InAppWebView is:

```
InAppWebViewGroupOptions options = InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
  crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
    mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture: false,
    javaScriptEnabled: true
  ),
  ios: IOSInAppWebViewOptions(
    allowsInlineMediaPlayback: true,
    allowsAirPlayForMediaPlayback: true
  ));
```

On main.dart I've put the permission request

```
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await Permission.camera.request();
  await Permission.microphone.request();
```

On Inflo.plist

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>This thing use camera</string>
<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
<string>This thing use the microfone</string>
<key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
```

On pod:

```
        ## dart: PermissionGroup.camera
        'PERMISSION_CAMERA=1',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.microphone
        'PERMISSION_MICROPHONE=1',
```

Everything is working fine.

The problem is that every time i open the InAppWebView, the message "Allow ... to use your camera and microphone?" appears.

How can I prevent that message to show up? I have permission in the app, how can I give to the InAppWebView?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8efW.png

Comment: same issue here. Have you found how to bypass the permission dialog that shows up every time?

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking for a solution to the iOS repromting problem, and this worked for me on version 5.4.3+7:

1. install the plugin in your project and refer to it in the pubspec file like this.

```
 flutter_inappwebview:
    path: "./custom_packages/flutter_inappwebview-5.4.3+7"
```

2. Inside the file `[YourPluginPath]\ios\Classes\InAppWebView\InAppWebView.swift`, add the following lines of code after the function `public func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!)`

```
@available(iOS 15, *)
public func webView(
    _ webView: WKWebView,
    requestMediaCapturePermissionFor origin: WKSecurityOrigin,
    initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo,
    type: WKMediaCaptureType,
    decisionHandler: @escaping (WKPermissionDecision) -> Void
) {
    decisionHandler(.grant)
}
```

[Source](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/prevent-for-reprompting-webrtc-webview-permissions-ios15/215240/2)